# Xero SDK - A validation exception occurred, DELETE method cannot be used on Bank accounts

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to delete account or updating account using xero api. Api is giving me exception with status code like 400

> A validation exception occurred, DELETE method cannot be used on Bank
>   accounts.

Attached is the code.

```
//deleting account using unique id
    xeroClient.deleteAccount("XXXXX-XxxxX-Xxxx-XXXX-XXXXXXX");

//setting deleted status via update()
Account account=new Account();

account.setAccountID("XXXXX-XxxxX-Xxxx-XXXX-XXXXXXX");

account.setStatus(AccountStatus.DELETED);

updateList.add(account);

xeroClient.updateAccount(updateList);
```

May I know why the exception I am getting while deleting account via Xero API

Answer (score 0):

According to the Xero [Documentation](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI.Net/blob/master/source/XeroApi.ConsoleTests/Program.cs#L149);

*Accounts of type 'BANK' cannot be updated*

It would appear that you have to do it manually through the web interface.